# Cannot use objectId (String) of one table passed from one fragment to another on click in WhereEqualTo query Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

When trying to pass objectId of a record as String from one fragment to another and use that id to query all the records from another table it is showing "pointer class expects pointer value" any suggestions.

Comment: can you your paste code here..

Comment: I now understood that we have pass entire object to whereEqualTo query andmy doubt is how to pass parseObject from fragment to another and do whereEqualTo query , I tried to use ParseProxyObject but cannot again reconvert to parseObject in result fragment

Comment: no, but as I understand the problem is different, I now have to pass the parseObject itself from one fragment to another.that's what I am searching how to do?!